# Rails 5 asset pipeline ignoring certain folders

Tags: sass, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

Ok, so I have some problems with the Rails 5 ignoring certain image folders. Here what is some relevant info:

```
app/assets
  javascripts/
  stylesheets/
    style1.scss
    style2.scss
  images/
    subfolder1/
    subfolder2/


config/initializers/assets.rb
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style1.css )
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( style2.css )

config/environments/development.rb
  config.assets.debug = true
```

So the problem I am running into is that assets are being fingerprinted and served ONLY from subfolder1. I think I know this because I can go into the Chrome developer tools, under the sources tab look at the compiled CSS files generated from style1.scss and style2.scss.

In the generated CSS the image-url tags from subfolder1 look like this:

```
background: url(/assets/subfolder1/image-106e9d1ebbbc3111ae3e5b153c81a7237b3d033ecdabad3e107e122c3b457ca5.jpg)
```

In the same generated CSS file, the image-url tags from subfolder2 look like this:

```
background: url(/images/subfolder2/image.png)
```

The images from subfolder1 get rendered, but the images from subfolder2 are never retrieved and generate 404s. Why will the scss to css conversion only correctly translate images from subfolder1? Why is it fingerprinting at all in development mode?

Comment: Strange. Could u try running rake assets:clean ?

Comment: Wow, that did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems like I needed to run rake assets:clean to get this to right itself. Thanks Joel_Blum!